# auto lisp to retrieve project names from drawings

Tags: autocad, autolisp

i have a client whose hard drive has crashed.  i was able to recover the data but only in enumerated files, no dates, sizes or any kind of naming scheme.  these are drawing files from autocad, and there is literally tens of thousands of these files.  the drawings do have title blocks but opening and renaming by hand, well that would take a century.  does anyone know of a lisp i can use to open the drawings and grab the text from the title block?  i have tried myself but have failed miserably.

Comment: Do the title blocks have text or attribute data?

Comment: and also what do you mean by "retrieve"... do you want to save them somewhere?

Comment: text no attribute, which  i think is the problem. i want to name the files what is in the title block.  thank you for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

If the text you require is always in the same location based on absolute coordinates and possibly layer/text style/text height/etc., you might still have a chance.

You could follow this type of pattern:

1. Open the document,
2. Zoom extents,
3. Select all text entities given the coordinates you need to search at using a bounding or crossing selection window,
4. Loop through the returned selection set (possibly comparing the contents of the text string with a regular expression for validation),
5. Extract the value if it's located correctly,
6. Store the current file name and the extracted text value in a CSV, XML, XLS file,
7. Close the document,
8. Repeat.

This will give you a complete list of all documents with the current name and the required name.  After you check it for duplicates, errors, or any other issues, it would be easy enough to write a function in Excel VBA (or another language) to rename each file as required.